# What temperature ranges are appropriate for a pet rabbit?

Tags: health, rabbits, containment, temperature

I have seen rabbits on TV living everywhere from the arctic to the desert.  Can I expect a pet rabbit to do well in the same range of temperatures as their wild cousins?  If not what  temperature ranges are appropriate for a domestic pet rabbit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the modern home environment, with both heat and air conditioning a domestic house rabbit should be comfortable.

There are multiple reliable references citing optimal temperature ranges.  These source are mostly for production and laboratory animals so I have chosen not to list them, but instead am summarizing the findings.

Most reference cite optimal temperatures in the 50 - 70 °F (10 - 22 °C) ranges,  with some sources allowing as low as 40 °F (5 °C) or as high as 80 °F (25 °F) being acceptable.

There is nearly universal recognition that temperatures above 85 °F (29 °C) are hazardous to domestic rabbits. At temperatures above 80 °F supplemental cooling should be offered, above 85 °F it is required. [(*see related*)](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2800).

On the cool side, temperatures above freezing are not considered unsafe for a healthy rabbit, if appropriate housing that allows good shelter and food are provided.  At 32 °F or 0 °C when water freezes, a rabbit that has had time to become acclimatized has lack of drinking water as a primary concern.

Temperatures that fall much below or stay below freezing for long periods, require supplemental heat [(*see related*)](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2790). Both to provide heat for the rabbit and to keep the water drinkable.

Comment: If you have more than one rabbit, temperatures under the freezing point (approximated -5°C - 10°C on the outside) are okay for them, if they have a hiding place with fitting space for them and no much left air space (for example a wooden box) which do not stays on the ground or has isolation to it. Inside this box they can hold the comfortable temperature by their own body warmth. Regardless freezing water is a problem. By the way: rabbits like snow! My have possibility to do all in snow free area, but they active choose the snow to play.

Comment: @Allerleirauh I am not a fan of leaving pets or children outside and unsupervised ever, and leaving them out when the temperature is below freezing I am even more strongly against.

Comment: In the areas where rabbits are natural from, freezing winters are normal. The only risk for they in nature is to less food. If they have enought food, their bodys are able to produce enought warmth to live comfortable. Second they need enought space to moving (not given in "normal" stables) so their muscles make them warm. For water they use to eat snow. Of course I give my rabbits energy rich food and guarantee they have liquid water to drink. The alternative would be to have them in the cellar all winter time...