# Keeping rabbits cool in extreme heat regions

Tags: rabbits, acclimation

I was wondering if anyone from extreme heat regions like the Phoenix AZ area have suggestions or thoughts on keeping and raising rabbits here?  I read through the ["how I can keep a rabbit cool"](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/2802/3424) thread wanted to know if there were more insight for those of us who live in climate zones that can get up to 112F during the summer.

I was looking to purchase some 'Californian' species of rabbits, are they more adapted to these dry & heat conditions of my area?  They would end up being in outdoor hutches and so any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated.  Maybe this idea is a No-Go for my climate...

Comment: Any suggestions on other species that are more acclimated to these high heat regions also appreciated.

Comment: Raising rabbits in outdoor hutches in Phoenix AZ is a No-Go.

Comment: well thats dissappointing, no other species? :(  I guess I will have to go back to raising Penguins here in Phoenix!

Comment: Actually I came across additional information to a solution from the website [AZRabbits.com](http://www.azrabbits.com/useful-information/dealing-with-heat.html).  they talk about misters can possibly reduce temperatures by up to 15 degrees (just make sure the misters do not point directly at the rabbits).  Also setup the hutches so they are under trees so not to recieve direct sunlight onto the hutches roofs. Along with what is stated in the linked question I feel it might be possible to raise rabbits in my zones extreme heat.

Comment: Those would not be solutions for pet rabbits, and this is a site for questions about pets.

Comment: @James how does this solution for heat tolerance have anything to do with if a rabbit is a pet or not?  Your comment is biased without reason.

Comment: Would you keep a dog or child outside in a hutch, under a tree with a mister in 112F weather?

Comment: my kids and dog play under misters on my back porch every summer for hours at a time every day