# Why is my bunny breathing fast? (About 120 Breaths per Minute)

Tags: health, rabbits

I noticed that his chest is rising and falling very fast. Is this anything to be concerned about?

Comment: The condition you describe could be indicative of an urgent or emergency health issue, please contact your vet for direction on how soon your pet needs to be seen. If someone knowledgeable in first aid is available, they may be able to write an answer, but you should not wait.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by others respiration of 120 per minute requires an immediate visit to the Vet. Normal Respiratory rate for rabbits is 30 - 60 breaths per minute.

References

- [Temperature, Heart and Respiration Rates](http://rabbit.org/temperature-and-respiration-rates/)
- [When your rabbit needs to see the vet NOW](http://www.rabbitwelfare.co.uk/resources/content/info-sheets/emergenc.htm)
- [Normal Temperatures, Pulse Rates and Respiration Rates for Pets](http://blog.vetdepot.com/normal-temperatures-pulse-rates-and-respiration-rates-for-pets)

**Observation** I am sitting in my home office with my rabbit & my laptop on my lap.  The Temperature in the room is 77, my feet are up on the desk and I am reaching over the rabbit to type. I looked down and notice she is breathing more than twice per second (i.e. 120+ per minute).  I took her back to her room where it is cooler.  A few minutes later she is resting on the floor and has a normal respiration rate.  It would seem that like many other furry animals rabbits breath faster when they are warm.  If your rabbit may be overly warm take a look at [How can I keep a rabbit cool?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2800)

Answer (score 0):

Look for help NOW, I once had one rabbit suffering from these because he was not properly protected from rain, it was pneumonia. 
As a general rule:

1. Make clean water always available.
2. Protect from sun, cold night and rain.
3. Provide a relaxed environment (e.g. without dogs barking).